# Does windows require a user-mode driver to be signed?

Tags: windows, device-driver, signing

I have an inf file for a user-mode driver for a device.

Does windows require me to get this driver signed?
Are there any risks of not having this driver signed?

I know that kernel-mode drivers need to be signed.

Comment: Look at the newer answer about windows 8 and 10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44923893/8356436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no; windows does not require signing for user-mode drivers on x86/x64.

There are no risks with not having it signed, and you don't have to pay the fee to have Microsoft sign the driver.

---

**UPDATE:**
This is no longer the case as Soroush Falahati's answer will point out, please refer to his answer

Comment: What about Windows 8?  I think even the INF files in Windows 8 have to be signed, so if your thing requires an INF file you need to start signing things.

Comment: Look at the newer answer about windows 8 and 10

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is right about Windows 7, but things are different starting with Windows 8 and now 10.

> User-mode drivers, like the Printer driver will install and work in an
>   x64-based computer. A dialog will appear to the user during
>   installation asking for approval to install the driver. Beginning in
>   Windows 8 and later versions of Windows, installation will not proceed
>   unless these driver packages are also signed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/windows-driver-signing-tutorial

Comment: That's talking about driver \*packages\* as a whole, not the driver binaries themselves (and it can fairly trivially be bypassed with test-signing). And while (in a very present sense) this is now a part of the full answer, insofar as OP was most definitively using Windows 7 the question to be sure was: in order to get them loaded, do you need to sign an UMDF *.dlls* the same way that you'd have to sign a *.sys*?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign it, but you can use self signed certificates with user-more drivers.

Comment: Just for the records, there's really no documentation at all explicitly confirming this (in fact, even what kind of signing you need for normal UMDF deployment is left unstated on MSDN). But I could find [multiple](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-driver-docs/issues/654#issuecomment-559054661) [developers](https://github.com/jloehr/HID-Wiimote/issues/5#issuecomment-827908025) stating that any cheap Authenticode certificate can do it for shipping to the public. I then infer in turn that verification must be happening out of the normal certificate stores, which you can easily manipulate.